# Drawing lines between JLabel in 2d array grid

Tags: java, swing, grid, 2d, jlabel

I'm trying to draw lines between cells which are JLabel but fail to get their coordinates.
The lines must follow a path from a startPoint to an endPoint.

In my View class, the below code creates the grid:

```
void createGrid(int rows, int cols) {

MyMouseListener listener = new MyMouseListener();
setRows(rows);

mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, 1, 1));
mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
mainPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
grid = new JLabel[rows][cols];
for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {
        grid[r][c] = new JLabel(iconMap.get(Token.VIDE));
        grid[r][c].addMouseListener(listener);
        grid[r][c].setOpaque(true);
        grid[r][c].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      //grid[r][c].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ICON_W, ICON_W));
        mainPanel.add(grid[r][c]);
    }
}
```

}

While this one creates the icons:

```
private Icon createIcon(Color color) {

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(ICON_W, ICON_W, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fillOval(1, 1, ICON_W - 2, ICON_W - 2); // int ICON_W = 20;
        g2.dispose();

        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }
```

The whole code for the View class: https://pastebin.com/sgyn6rSR
Code for the path algo: https://pastebin.com/Gcw9YVMF

I've tried something like below, but doesn't work

```
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

           for (JLabel[] grid : cells) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                Point startPoint = grid[0].getLocation();
                Point endPoint = grid[1].getLocation();
                startPoint.x += (grid[0].getWidth() / 2);
                startPoint.y += (grid[1].getHeight()/ 2);
                endPoint.x += (grid[0].getWidth() / 2);
                endPoint.y += (grid[1].getHeight()/ 2);

                if(startPoint != null){
                g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(startPoint, endPoint));
            }

            startPoint = endPoint;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the View class modified to add lines as requested.

Please review and see comments :

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class View {

    public static final String CELL_SELECTION = "cell selection";
    private final static int GAP = 2;
    private static int iconWidth;
    private int rows;

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JLabel[][] grid;
    private Map<Token, Icon> iconMap = new EnumMap<>(Token.class);
    private int selectedRow;
    private int selectedCol;

    //a collection of cells representing a path
    private CellsList path;

    //a pane to hold two panels one on top of the other
    JPanel layeredPanel;

    View() {

        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        //add layerd pane to hold two panels one on top of the other
        layeredPanel = new JPanel();

        //set GridBagLayout to allow placing two components one on top of the other
        layeredPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
          GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
          gbc.gridx = 0;
          gbc.gridy = 0;
          gbc.weightx = 1;
          gbc.weighty = 1;
          gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        //add main panel to layered panel
        layeredPanel.add(mainPanel, gbc);

        //create and add a drawing panel
        DrawJPanel drawPanel = new DrawJPanel();
        drawPanel.setOpaque(false); //set if to transparent so it does not
                                    //hide mainPanel under it
        layeredPanel.add(drawPanel, gbc);

        //set z-order (depth) of two panels
        layeredPanel.setComponentZOrder(mainPanel,1);
        layeredPanel.setComponentZOrder(drawPanel,0);
    }

    void createGrid(int rows, int cols) {

        MyMouseListener listener = new MyMouseListener();
        setRows(rows);
        setIcons();

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, 1, 1));
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        grid = new JLabel[rows][cols];
        for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {
                grid[r][c] = new JLabel(iconMap.get(Token.VIDE));
                grid[r][c].addMouseListener(listener);
                grid[r][c].setOpaque(true);
                grid[r][c].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                mainPanel.add(grid[r][c]);
            }
        }

        layeredPanel.setPreferredSize(mainPanel.getPreferredSize());
    }

    int getSelectedRow() {
        return selectedRow;
    }

    int getSelectedCol() {
        return selectedCol;
    }

    void setCell(Token token, int row, int col) {

        grid[row][col].setIcon(iconMap.get(token));
    }

    int getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    void setRows(int rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    //added to each cell to listen to mouse clicks
    //fires property change with cell index
    private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JLabel selection = (JLabel) e.getSource();
            for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {
                    if (selection == grid[r][c]) {
                        selectedRow = r;
                        selectedCol = c;
                        int index = (r * grid[r].length) + c;
                        mainPanel.firePropertyChange(CELL_SELECTION, -1, index);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void start() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MVC Pha");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(layeredPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //add listener to listen to property changes fired by MyMouseListener
    void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener viewListener) {

        mainPanel.addPropertyChangeListener(viewListener);
    }

    void setPath(CellsList path) {

        this.path = path;
        if(path != null) {
            drawPath();
        }
    }
    //highlight path by changing background color.
    //It can be changed to draw lines between cells
    private void drawPath() {

        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {

                if((path != null) && path.contains(new int[] {row,col})) {
                    grid[row][col].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                } else {
                    grid[row][col].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //receives rectangle and returns its center point
    private Point getComponentCenter(Rectangle bounds) {

        int xCenter = (int) ((bounds.getX()+ bounds.getMaxX())/2);
        int yCenter  = (int) ((bounds.getMinY()+ bounds.getMaxY())/2);
        return new Point(xCenter, yCenter);
    }

    void refresh() {

        layeredPanel.repaint();
    }

    private void setIcons() {

        if(rows <= 20) {
            iconWidth = 24;
        } else if( rows <= 40 ) {
            iconWidth = 20;
        } else if( rows <= 60 ) {
            iconWidth = 15;
        } else if( rows <= 80 ) {
            iconWidth = 12;
        } else {
            iconWidth = 8;
        }

        iconMap.put(Token.VIDE, createIcon(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        iconMap.put(Token.CERCLE_BLEU, createIcon(Color.BLUE));
        iconMap.put(Token.CERCLE_ROUGE, createIcon(Color.RED));
    }

    private Icon createIcon(Color color) {

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(iconWidth, iconWidth, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fillOval(1, 1, iconWidth - GAP, iconWidth - GAP);
        g2.dispose();

        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }

    //a panel to draw line on
    class DrawJPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

            super.paintComponent(g);

            if((path == null) || path.isEmpty() ) {
                return;
            }

            //calculate points to construct line along the path
            Point[] polygon = new Point[path.size()];

            int i=0;
            for(int[] address : path) { //iterate over path

                //get cell location (row / col)
                int row = address[0]; int col = address[1];

                //get label in that location
                JLabel lable = grid[row][col];

                //add center of label as a point in polygon
                polygon[i++] = getComponentCenter(lable.getBounds());
            }

            //draw points in polygon
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN); //set line color and width
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < (polygon.length -1); j++)       {

                Point point1 = polygon[j];
                Point point2 = polygon[j+1];
                g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(point1, point2));
            }

            //add line to connect last point to first
           g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(polygon[j], polygon[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved me countless hours of trying to make it work. Thank you

Comment: But I would like to know, why use Line2D.Float instead of Line2D.Double is there any difference here?

Comment: You can use both. Double has a higher accuracy (and memory usage) which is not really needed here

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks. But I have noticed lines drawn are not saved, they disappear whenever I click on a cell, same case with the background color

Comment: Is there a way to save their position?

Comment: This only answers the question asked. You need to study the code: when you click a cell and modify it as you please. (When you click a cell a new path calculation starts so the old path is cleared. If you want to store it, do so)

Comment: Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958950/storing-path-from-a-2d-array-grid-into-a-list

Answer (score 2):

Override the `paintComponent()` method of the panel you add the labels to.

The basic code would be:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (int i = 0; i < getComponentCount() - 1; i++)
    {
        Component component1 = getComponent(i);
        Point point1 = component1.getLocation();
        Component component2 = getComponent(i + 1);
        Point point2 = component2.getLocation();

        g.drawLine(point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y);
    }
}
```

Once you get this working you can modify the logic to draw the line from the from/to the center of each component.

Comment: Will this follow the path ? I have overriden paintComponent Please have a look at the code on pastebin

Comment: @esQmo We don't look at code on pastebin. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. All you need is some code to add a few  labels to a panel. Then you add the custom logic I provided. You then add the panel to a frame. The whole `MCVE` will be about 30 lines of code. Once you understand the basic concept you then incorporate the solution into your real application. The code I provide will draw the line in the order the components are added to the panel. If you have a different order then you would modify the approach to go through your List

Answer (score 2):

That took a long time.  Sorry but I have a lot of context to the original question, including the base `View` and `Path` code :P

[image: Test Result]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DebugGraphics;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class View extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DrawLines drawLines = new DrawLines();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setGlassPane(drawLines);
                frame.add(new View(20, 20, drawLines));
                frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    enum Token {
        VIDE, CERCLE_BLEU, CERCLE_ROUGE
    }

    private static final int ICON_W = 20;
    public static final String CELL_SELECTION = "cell selection";
    private int rows;

    private Token[][] tokens;
    private JLabel[][] grid;
    private Map<Token, Icon> iconMap = new EnumMap<>(Token.class);
    private int selectedRow;
    private int selectedCol;

    //a collection of cells representing a path
    private ArrayList<Cell> path;

    private DrawLines drawLines;

    View(int rows, int cols, DrawLines drawLines) {
        this.drawLines = drawLines;
        iconMap.put(Token.VIDE, createIcon(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        iconMap.put(Token.CERCLE_BLEU, createIcon(Color.BLUE));
        iconMap.put(Token.CERCLE_ROUGE, createIcon(Color.RED));
        createGrid(rows, cols);
    }

    private Icon createIcon(Color color) {

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(ICON_W, ICON_W, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fillOval(1, 1, ICON_W - 2, ICON_W - 2);
        g2.dispose();

        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }

    void createGrid(int rows, int cols) {

        tokens = new Token[rows][cols];

        MyMouseListener listener = new MyMouseListener();
        setRows(rows);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, 1, 1));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid = new JLabel[rows][cols];
        for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {
                grid[r][c] = new JLabel(iconMap.get(Token.VIDE));
                grid[r][c].addMouseListener(listener);
                grid[r][c].setOpaque(true);
                grid[r][c].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                grid[r][c].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ICON_W, ICON_W));
                add(grid[r][c]);
            }
        }

        set(6, 6, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(6, 7, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(6, 8, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(6, 9, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(7, 9, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(8, 9, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(9, 9, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(10, 9, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(10, 6, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(10, 7, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(10, 8, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(10, 9, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(7, 6, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(8, 6, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        set(9, 6, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
//
//        set(7, 6, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
//        set(7, 7, Token.CERCLE_BLEU);
//        set(7, 8, Token.CERCLE_BLEU);
//
//        set(8, 6, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
//        set(8, 7, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
//        set(8, 8, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
//
//        set(5, 7, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
//        set(5, 8, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
//        set(5, 9, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
//        set(6, 9, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
//        set(7, 9, Token.CERCLE_ROUGE);
        Path path = new Path(tokens);
        if (path.findPath(new int[]{6, 6})) {
            setPath(path.getPath());
        }
    }

    void set(int row, int col, Token token) {
        grid[row][col].setIcon(iconMap.get(token));
        tokens[row][col] = token;
    }

    int getSelectedRow() {
        return selectedRow;
    }

    int getSelectedCol() {
        return selectedCol;
    }

    void setCell(Token token, int row, int col) {

        grid[row][col].setIcon(iconMap.get(token));
    }

    int getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    void setRows(int rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    //added to each cell to listen to mouse clicks
    //fires property change with cell index
    private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JLabel selection = (JLabel) e.getSource();
            for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {
                    if (selection == grid[r][c]) {
                        selectedRow = r;
                        selectedCol = c;
                        int index = (r * grid[r].length) + c;
                        selection.setIcon(iconMap.get(Token.CERCLE_BLEU));
                        tokens[selectedRow][selectedCol] = Token.CERCLE_BLEU;
                        System.out.println(c + "x" + r + " = " + index);
                        firePropertyChange(CELL_SELECTION, -1, index);

                        Path path = new Path(tokens);
                        if (path.findPath(new int[]{selectedRow, selectedCol})) {
                            setPath(path.getPath());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //add listener to listen to property changes fired by MyMouseListener
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener viewListener) {

        addPropertyChangeListener(viewListener);
    }

    void setPath(ArrayList<Cell> path) {

        this.path = path;
        if (path != null) {
            drawPath();
        }
    }

    //highlight path by changing background color. 
    //It can be changed to draw lines between cells
    private void drawPath() {
        if (path != null) {
            List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>(25);
            for (Cell cell : path) {
                JLabel label = grid[cell.y][cell.x];
                label.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                labels.add(label);
            }
            for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {

                    if (!path.contains(new Cell(c, r))) {
                        grid[r][c].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    }

                }
            }

            drawLines.setPath(labels);
        }
    }

    void refresh() {

        repaint();
    }

//This is what I added to try drawing lines
    public static class DrawLines extends JLabel {

        List<JLabel> path;

        public void setPath(List<JLabel> path) {
            this.path = new ArrayList<>(path);
            this.path.add(path.get(0));
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (path != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                Point startPoint = null;
                for (JLabel label : path) {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                    Point endPoint = label.getLocation();
                    endPoint.x += (label.getWidth() / 2);
                    endPoint.y += (label.getHeight() / 2);
                    if (startPoint != null) {
                        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Float(startPoint, endPoint));
                    }
                    startPoint = endPoint;
                }
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

    class Cell {

        private int x, y;

        public Cell(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 7;
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Cell other = (Cell) obj;
            if (this.x != other.x) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.y != other.y) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return x + "x" + y;
        }

    }

    class Path extends Stack<Cell> {

        private Token[][] grid;

        //a path shorter than min can not surround any cell
        private static final int MIN_PATH_LEGTH = 3;

        //a collection of cells that has been tested
        private ArrayList<Cell> checked;

        //represents the cell where the search starts from
        Cell origin;
        //represents the token of the origin
        Token originToken;

        private int rows;
        private int cols;

        Path(Token[][] grid) {

            this.grid = grid;
            rows = grid.length;
            cols = grid[0].length;
        }

        //search for a path
        boolean findPath(int[] origin) {

            int row = origin[0], col = origin[1];
            this.origin = new Cell(col, row);

            //represents the token of the origin
            originToken = grid[row][col];

            //initialize list of checked items
            checked = new ArrayList<>();

            boolean found = findPath(row, col);

            if (found) {
                printPath();
            } else {
                System.out.println("No path found");
            }

            return found;
        }

        //recursive method to find path. a cell is represented by its row, col
        //returns true when path was found
        private boolean findPath(int row, int col) {

            //check if cell has the same token as origin
            if (grid[row][col] != originToken) {
                return false;
            }

            Cell cell = new Cell(col, row);

            //check if this cell was tested before to avoid checking again
            if (checked.contains(cell)) {
                return false;
            }

            //get cells neighbors
            ArrayList<Cell> neighbors = getNeighbors(row, col);

            //check if solution found. If path size > min and cell
            //neighbors contain the origin it means that path was found
            if ((size() >= MIN_PATH_LEGTH) && neighbors.contains(origin)) {

                add(cell);
                return true;
            }

            //add cell to checked list
            checked.add(cell);

            //add cell to path
            add(cell);

            //if path was not found check cell neighbors
            for (Cell neighbor : neighbors) {

                boolean found = findPath(neighbor.getY(), neighbor.getX());
                if (found) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            //path not found
            pop(); //remove last element from stack
            return false;
        }

        //return a list of all neighbors of cell row, col
        private ArrayList<Cell> getNeighbors(int row, int col) {

            ArrayList<Cell> neighbors = new ArrayList<Cell>();

            for (int colNum = col - 1; colNum <= (col + 1); colNum += 1) {

                for (int rowNum = row - 1; rowNum <= (row + 1); rowNum += 1) {

                    if (!((colNum == col) && (rowNum == row))) {

                        if (withinGrid(rowNum, colNum)) {

                            neighbors.add(new Cell(colNum, rowNum));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return neighbors;
        }

        private boolean withinGrid(int colNum, int rowNum) {

            if ((colNum < 0) || (rowNum < 0)) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((colNum >= cols) || (rowNum >= rows)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        //use for testing
        private void printPath() {
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",", "Path: ", "");
            for (Cell cell : this) {
                sj.add(cell.toString());
            }
            System.out.println(sj);

        }

        public ArrayList<Cell> getPath() {
            ArrayList<Cell> cl = new ArrayList<>();
            cl.addAll(this);
            return cl;
        }
    }
}
```

> But The lines are not repainting. Is there as way to save them?

The `DrawLines` will draw the path you pass it.  To provide a "history", you need to maintain another `List` of all the paths you pass, for example...

```
public static class DrawLines extends JLabel {

    private List<List<JLabel>> history;

    public DrawLines() {
        history = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public void setPath(List<JLabel> path) {
        List<JLabel> copy = new ArrayList<>(path);
        copy.add(path.get(0));

        history.add(copy);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        Point startPoint = null;
        for (List<JLabel> path : history) {
            for (JLabel label : path) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                Point endPoint = label.getLocation();
                endPoint.x += (label.getWidth() / 2);
                endPoint.y += (label.getHeight() / 2);
                if (startPoint != null) {
                    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Float(startPoint, endPoint));
                }
                startPoint = endPoint;
            }
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Works as expected, unfortunately no way to accept more than 1 answer. But The lines are not repainting. Is there as way to save them?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve, but, DrawPanel creates a new List of the JLabels, so, you could have another List into which you add those paths

Comment: Yes, will try that approach then come back if stuck somewhere.

Comment: Didn't find a way out, please can you assist?

Comment: It finds paths even when there is none!

Comment: Don't ask me, it's your code ;) - Create a very simple example, remove the UI from it, have only the path finding code and supporting code (ie the `Cell`), put together a series of example data which and be used to duplicate your issue, explain your expected results and actual results in new question

Answer (score 1):

The following answer present the same solution as in my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43910937/3992939). 

For the benefit of  all (other users, those who try to answer, as well as for the poster), I think the question should have been asked and answer as a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map; 
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class View {

    private static final String WHITE = "white";
    private static final String BLUE = "blue";

    private final static int GAP = 2;
    private static final int iconWidth = 24;

    private Map<String, Icon> iconMap = new HashMap<>();

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JLabel[][] grid;

    //a collection of cells representing a path
    private ArrayList<int[]> path;

    //a pane to hold two panels one on top of the other
    JPanel layeredPanel;

    View(int rows) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Line between JLabels");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        //add layered pane to hold two panels one on top of the other
        layeredPanel = new JPanel();

        //set GridBagLayout to allow placing two components one on top of the other
        layeredPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
          GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
          gbc.gridx = 0;
          gbc.gridy = 0;
          gbc.weightx = 1;
          gbc.weighty = 1;
          gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        //add main panel to layered panel
        layeredPanel.add(mainPanel, gbc);

        //create and add a drawing panel
        DrawJPanel drawPanel = new DrawJPanel();
        drawPanel.setOpaque(false); //set if to transparent so it does not
                                    //hide mainPanel under it
        layeredPanel.add(drawPanel, gbc);

        //set z-order (depth) of two panels
        layeredPanel.setComponentZOrder(mainPanel,1);
        layeredPanel.setComponentZOrder(drawPanel,0);

        path = new ArrayList<>();
        setTestData();
        createGrid(rows,rows);

        frame.getContentPane().add(layeredPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    void createGrid(int rows, int cols) {

        setIcons();

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, 1, 1));
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        grid = new JLabel[rows][cols];
        for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {
                if(isInPath(new int[] {r,c})) {
                    grid[r][c] = new JLabel(iconMap.get(BLUE));
                } else {
                    grid[r][c] = new JLabel(iconMap.get(WHITE));
                }
                grid[r][c].setOpaque(true);
                grid[r][c].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                mainPanel.add(grid[r][c]);
            }
        }

        layeredPanel.setPreferredSize(mainPanel.getPreferredSize());
    }

    //receives rectangle and returns its center point
    private Point getComponentCenter(Rectangle bounds) {

        int xCenter = (int) ((bounds.getX()+ bounds.getMaxX())/2);
        int yCenter  = (int) ((bounds.getMinY()+ bounds.getMaxY())/2);
        return new Point(xCenter, yCenter);
    }

    private void setIcons() {

        iconMap.put(WHITE, createIcon(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        iconMap.put(BLUE, createIcon(Color.BLUE));
    }

    private Icon createIcon(Color color) {

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(iconWidth, iconWidth, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fillOval(1, 1, iconWidth - GAP, iconWidth - GAP);
        g2.dispose();

        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }

    private boolean isInPath(int[] cell) {

        if((path == null) || path.isEmpty() ) {
            return false;
        }

        for(int[] p : path) {

            if((cell[0]== p[0]) && (cell[1] == p[1])) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    //a panel to draw line on
    class DrawJPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

            super.paintComponent(g);

            if((path == null) || path.isEmpty() ) {
                return;
            }

            //calculate points to construct line along the path
            Point[] polygon = new Point[path.size()];

            int i=0;
            for(int[] address : path) { //iterate over path

                //get cell location (row / col)
                int row = address[0]; int col = address[1];

                //get label in that location
                JLabel lable = grid[row][col];

                //add center of label as a point in polygon
                polygon[i++] = getComponentCenter(lable.getBounds());
            }

            //draw points in polygon
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN); //set line color and width
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < (polygon.length -1); j++)       {

                Point point1 = polygon[j];
                Point point2 = polygon[j+1];
                g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(point1, point2));
            }

            //add line to connect last point to first
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(polygon[j], polygon[0]));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new View(10);
    }

    private void setTestData() {

        path.add(new int[] {3,3});
        path.add(new int[] {3,4});
        path.add(new int[] {3,5});
        path.add(new int[] {4,6});
        path.add(new int[] {5,5});
        path.add(new int[] {5,4});
        path.add(new int[] {5,3});
        path.add(new int[] {4,4});
    }
}
```